# Read excel file with password protection from nodejs

Tags: node.js, excel, password-protection

Have a task, to parse password protected excel-file. Is there any library to work with password protected files for nodejs? I have explored ExcelJS and Node-xlsx, but there are no info about password protected files...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found lib for node js https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-populate
it working with password-protected excel files

Comment: i tried with xlsx-populate but getting this error .....

Could not find a declaration file for module 'xlsx-populate' 
 /passwordprotect/node_modules/xlsx-populate/lib/XlsxPopulate.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/xlsx-populate` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'xlsx-populate';`ts(7016)