# Unable to read protacted excel file by using exceljs

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor

I am automating one scenario where I am trying to read downloaded .xlsx file. But downloaded file is protacted one, is there any way to read this file by using any JavaScript or typescript library.
Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50343273/10836734

Comment: Thanks @DublinDev its working for me

Comment: Glad to hear it!